# Spring Data MongoDB save id as UUID String, not object

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-jpa

In my current app, when I save an entity, it saves the ID as LUUID("some hex")
I want to change the behaviour, so that it saves the ID just as String (UUID.toString())

What are the needed changes for it? Is it safe to change the datatype of the entity ID from UUID to String? Do we need a Codec Registry here?

Thanks!

Comment: It's 100% ok to change this.  When you change your Id to a String, you'll be responsible for setting its value, and you'll need to update your existing records to convert the UUID to their String representations.

Comment: that is the way I going to solve this task. Thanks!